# Print sum of a calculation without metadata prefix provided by var_dump()

Tags: php, sum, integer, output

I have this code which calculates the sum of "letter numbers" in a string, but its output is: `int(64)`. `64` is the total of `T`(20), `E`(2), `S`(19), `T`(20) --> `20+5+19+20=64`.

I want only number as output `64` instead of `int(64)`.

Here is the code:

```
$data = "test";
$testResult = array_values(
    array_merge(
        array_fill_keys(
            range('A','Z'),
            0
        ),
        array_count_values(
            str_split(
                strtoupper($data)
            )
        )
    )
);
$wordCount = 0;
foreach ($testResult as $letterValue => $letterCount) {
    $wordCount += ++$letterValue * $letterCount;
}
var_dump($wordCount);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int(64)` is a feature of [`var_dump()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/var_dump). Just `echo` the variable and you should get normal numerical output.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your actual script, it can be simplified by summing the the `ord()` value of each letter (less 96, because [lowercase letters start from 97 on the Ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/characters/ascii-alphabet-characters)).  My script assumes that only single-byte lowercase letters will be used as input.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5JqC2))

```
$data = "test";
echo array_reduce(
         str_split($data),
         fn($sum, $char) => $sum + ord($char) - 96,
     );
// outputs: 64
```

---

Beyond that snippet, `var_dump()`'s output includes metadata about the value.

There are several functions and language constructs that you can choose from to present your data. It is important to remember though that while technique has nuanced behaviour, if you are printing data to a document (html, txt, or something else), non-flat data types will need to be converted to a flat data type.  Notice in the demonstration below that some data types are displayed differently or not at all when printed.  For non-flat data, my demo will encode the data as a JSON string, but there are different ways to generate a flatten value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CoAFd))

```
$tests = [
    'false' => false,
    'true' => true,
    'null' => null,
    '0' => 0,
    '0.1' => 0.1,
    'a' => 'a',
    '[\'foo\']' => ['foo'],
    '(object) [\'bar\', \'bar\']' => (object) ['bar', 'bar'],
];

echo "<table border=1>";
    echo '<tr><th>input</th><th>echo</th><th>printf</th><th>print_r</th><th>var_export</th><th>var_dump</th></tr>';
    foreach ($tests as $input => $test) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>$input</th><td>";
        echo is_array($test) || is_object($test) ? json_encode($test) : $test;
        echo "</td><td>";
        printf('%s', is_array($test) || is_object($test) ? json_encode($test) : $test);
        echo "</td><td>";
        print_r($test);
        echo "</td><td>";
        var_export($test);
        echo "</td><td>";
        var_dump($test);
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $wordCount;
```

instead of

```
var_dump($wordCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump gives you all information about a variable the (int) lets you know it is an integer, if you just echo it out you won't see the (int).

Answer (score 0):

PHP function [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) displays structured information the variable and its type in addition to its value. You simply need to [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [print()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use echo instead of var_dump. Var_dump gives you additional information about the variable. If $wordCount was an array instead of an int, it will display Array(size){values...}

read the manual of vardump [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

i hope this will solve your problem.
greets,
stefan